# Maximal Domain of Continuity

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, polish-spaces

Let $f:(X,T)\rightarrow (Y,S)$ be a function between Polish spaces.  Does there necessarily exists a *(non-trivial: ie not a point or the emptyset)* open subset $\tilde{X}\subseteq X$, on which $f|_{\tilde{X}}$ becomes continuous.

Note: a maximum here (is not necessarily unique).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there need not exist such an open set. Just consider $X=Y=\Bbb R$ (with standard topology) and 
$$ f(x)=x+\mathbf 1_{\Bbb Q}(x).$$